# Refresh/Access updated Entities outside the transaction in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions, transactionscope

I am spawning a `new`Spring transaction inside a `readonly` Spring transaction. The new transaction is creating an entry in DB. After coming out of the new transaction I am **not** able to fetch the data in the `readonly` transaction, though the entry has been created in the DB at that point.

```
    Interface A {
      @Transactional(readOnly = true)
      void methodA();
    }

    Interface B {
      @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
      void methodB();
    }

    Class classA implements A {
      public void methodA() {
            classB.methodB();
            // select * from Employee where id = 1
            // Problem: This returns nothing, maybe because it belongs to different transaction. 
            // >>>>>>>>>>> How can i access it here <<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
    }


    Class classB implements B {
      public void methodB() {
             // Code to: insert into table Employee(id) values(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your transaction isolation level?

Comment: @MichaelWiles, Thanks a lot for replying. How do you define transaction isolation in Spring? I don't have an idea about it.

Comment: It's a property on the datasource. Strictly not a spring thing. see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o65asktom-082389.html. Most dataSource implementations that spring uses have property for setting the transaction isolation level